# Can someone tell me how I can host my MVC 3 application on linux server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hosting

I need to call my ASP.NET pages by passing them extensions. Suppose home index page need to be call `/home/index/a.aspx` a.aspx doesn't matter what I call it's just work because I made `Index()` action in home.

If I call them without extensions. he call PHP page from root directory.
Second problem is this code not working on server (I can play it on my machine)

```
  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Admin")</li>
```

I am not know ASP.NET webform very well nor PHP so that's why I use MVC framework. I have too many problem in my application running on server. It's run on my own system with no problem.

When I call Hosting server they tell me that I need to use IIS7 for this. Currently our server is linux ,apache (as support tell me). I don't know what they means for "they have installed .net 4 on server".

Please, Can someone help me then this one page application will work. I have 5-6 page in whole application. I am worried about if something not working in my application.

Comment: basically .NET is designed for Windows OS, but projects like [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried mono? Mono is a project that is mostly compatible with .NET.

Comment: thanks a lot for suggestion. Actually someone else own the server (I don't). I can't change any settings on server. I just can change in my application that they are able to run them on their server.